# mPDF Index at Second page

Tags: php, mpdf

How can I display the Index of my document on the second page? 
With the InsertIndex it´s going into the last one.

Code:

```
    $content.="<indexentry content='First'/>";
    $content.="TEXT";
    $content.="<indexentry content='Second'/>";
    $content.="TEXT";
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($content);
    $mpdf->InsertIndex(true, false, "es_ES.utf8", "Spanish_Spain");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK seems like u can´t

"No, not ATM, and it is not even planned. Marking as feature request."

https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/issues/423